# Guidance with a SQL query - results duplicating

Tags: php, sql, phpmyadmin

Really need some guidance, I have a website where people can upload images to competitions and they get a result (marks), I want to pull out a LEADERSHIP BOARD to see how everyone is doing. However the SQL Query I have has people names duplicated, could someone tell me where to alter my query so the results for say 1 person entering 3 competitions are added up, and only the TOTAL marks are stated once in the output. The results are kept in `tblMembEntComp` `fldResult`.

**What I'm currently getting:**

[image: Leadership Board]

**My PHP Code:**

```
<p><b>LEADERSHIP BOARD</b></p>
<?php
    $query = "SELECT `tblMember`.`fldFName`, `tblMember`.`fldSName`, `tblMembEntComp`.`fldResult` FROM `tblMember` AS `tblMember` JOIN `tblMembEntComp` as `tblMembEntComp` ON `tblMember`.`fldMemberID` = `tblMembEntComp`.`fldMemberID`ORDER BY `fldResult` DESC";

    $result = $conn -> query($query);

    while($row = $result -> fetch_assoc()) 
        {
            echo $row['fldFName']." ".$row['fldSName']." ".$row['fldResult']."<br>";
        } 
?>
```

**UPDATE:**
I have tried the `GROUP BY` function as suggested by user below however I am getting thrown the error:

[image: SQL Error]

Comment: You can retrieve the current scores by using something unique of the user. For example an email address

Comment: Are the names unique? `group by` and `sum` come to mind

Comment: Hi @user3783243 I haven't used SUM yet, do you know where about in the query this SUM would go?

Comment: It depends, if the names aren't unique you won't be able to use it because you'll add two different people together.

Comment: @user3783243 so yes there will be unique `fldMemberID` 's?

Comment: I think something like `select fldMemberID, name columns, SUM(integer_column) from table group by fldMemberID, name columns` will do it in that case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want an aggregation query.  Something like:

```
SELECT m.fldSName, SUM(mec.fldResult) as fldResult
FROM tblMember m JOIN 
     tblMembEntComp mec
     ON m.fldMemberID =mec.fldMemberID
GROUP BY m.fldSName
ORDER BY SUM(mec.fldResult) DESC
```

Comment: I think this has done it however I do not understand that logic at all, being a newbie. So the `m.` and the `mec.`   are just placeholders if you like for the table names to write short hand? Where would I add in fldFName too into the output please, so its first name, surname , then result :-) P.S You rock

Comment: @K.Haydock . . . The `m` and `mec` are *table aliases*.  They are used as abbreviations for table names to qualify columns (that is, including the table reference in the column name as in `m.fldSName`).

Comment: Got it thank you, I tried to add in m.fldFname just at the beginning after SELECT but it doesn't like that. Do you know the correct place to add that column in so the output is firstName, surName, Result :-)

Comment: @K.Haydock . . . Any columns you include in the `SELECT` either need to be the arguments of aggregation functions (such as `MIN()`) or in the `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: Hi @GordonLinoff I know a while has past but I re-read over the query and thought I had repeated the table names where you had placed the m and the mec after the table names, i.e. `FROM tblMember tblMember JOIN tblMembEntComp tblMembEntComp` so I deleted one of each and the query no longer worked, can I ask why we repeat the table names straight after one another?

Comment: @K.Haydock . . . My answer does not repeat the table names.  It introduces shorter table aliases.

Comment: Ah, sorry Gordon for some reason I wrote it as above then used the aliases also, suprisingly it worked haha with duplicate names one after another but corrected it your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You should group by query by `tblMember` primary key as below:

```
<?php
    $query = "SELECT `tblMember`.`fldFName`, `tblMember`.`fldSName`, `tblMembEntComp`.`fldResult`, `tblMember`.`fldId` FROM `tblMember` AS `tblMember` JOIN `tblMembEntComp` as `tblMembEntComp` ON `tblMember`.`fldMemberID` = `tblMembEntComp`.`fldMemberID` GROUP BY `tblMember`.`fldId` ORDER BY `fldResult` DESC";

    $result = $conn -> query($query);

    while($row = $result -> fetch_assoc()) 
        {
            echo $row['fldFName']." ".$row['fldSName']." ".$row['fldResult']."<br>";
        } 
?>
```

You can update group by field as your primary key. Hope it helps you :)

Comment: A `SUM` also will be needed. Otherwise the query will just pick one of the multiple values at random and display it.

Comment: Hi, I tried the above with saying GROUP BY tblMember.fldMemberID,  however I get an error thrown: `#1055 - Expression #3 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'photographyclub.tblMembEntComp.fldResult' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by`

Comment: @K.Haydock You are using mysql 5.7+?

Comment: MAMP 5.2 and it says it's up to date on the home page of it :-)

Comment: @K.Haydock I dunno `MAMP`, can you connect to the mysql instance and see what it is running? `select @@version`.

Comment: @K.Haydock to resolve above error, you need to select primary field in select as well. As this: SELECT `tblMember`.`fldFName`, `tblMember`.`fldSName`, `tblMembEntComp`.`fldResult`, `tblMember`.`fldId` FROM `tblMember` AS `tblMember` JOIN `tblMembEntComp` as `tblMembEntComp` ON `tblMember`.`fldMemberID` = `tblMembEntComp`.`fldMemberID` GROUP BY `tblMember`.`fldId` ORDER BY `fldResult` DESC

Comment: Hi @RohitMittal, I just tried this also, and the same error is appearing which is really weird, it doesn't seem to like the GROUP BY. `SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column` but the logic sounds perfectly correct....confusing!